# Bootstrap Collapse No Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently making a list that creates categories based on user input through a text field. Each time the create button is clicked my JavaScript is called and adds a div that should be collapsible to show a list.

Right now I only have a button collapsing underneath but there will be additional content after I can get the collapse operational.

HTML: The JQuery UI is for potential drag-drop functionality later:

```
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.3.0.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- 
Bootstrap is a lightweight and relativley flexible framework that is great for responsive sites.
Although there are some downsides, as with almost anything, it is great for getting a good looking site up and running quickly.
This would allow this To Do List to be used just as easily on a mobile device while still maintaining an attractive look. 
-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="h1 row text-center" id="main-header">To Do List</div>

        <div class="row" id="category-anchor">
            <div role="form" class="form-inline">
                <label id="category-label">New Category: </label>
                <input type="text" id="new-category" class="form-control">
                <button id="create-category" class="btn btn-primary form-control" onClick="createCategory()">Create</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <li id="anchor">
        </li>

    </div>

</body>
<script src="todo.js"></script>
</html>
```

Here is my tiny bit of CSS:

```
* {
    font-family: Serif;
}

#main-header {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #00ffff;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

#category-label {
    font-size: 150%;
}

#create-category {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var categoryID = 0;
var todoListID = 1000;

function createCategory() {
    var newCategory = document.getElementById("new-category").value;
    if(newCategory.trim().length != 0) {
        var categoryRow = '<div id="' + categoryID + '" class="category">';
        categoryRow += '<div class="h2 row text-center" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#' + todoListID + '">' + newCategory + '</div>';
        categoryRow += '</div>';
        document.getElementById("new-category").value = "";
    }

    $(categoryRow).appendTo("#anchor");

    addToDoList();
    categoryID++;
    todoListID++;
}

function addToDoList() {
    var list = '<div id="' + todoListID + '" class="list collapse">';
    list += '<div class="row">';
    list += '<button class="btn btn-success create-list">New ToDo</button>';
    list += '</div>';
    list += '</div>';

    $(list).appendTo("#" + categoryID);
}
```

If I use "collapse in" the button shows but the above div is still not collapsible.

Comment: A [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) showing your html, css and jquery would be a massive help.

Comment: The button isn't closed properly. It ends with a closing `div` tag instead of `</button>`

Comment: Nice catch! Unfortunately the problem persists though.

Comment: I still don't fully understand your problem. Are you saying that only the first category is collapsible and all additional ones are not?

Comment: None are collapsible. I can't see the content but it is present in the DOM. If I throw in "list collapse in" instead of just "list collapse" I can see the content but the collapse functionality is still unavailable.

Comment: Is this doing what you are expecting: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/cc3yL1of/)?

Comment: That works beautifully but I can't see what you changed aside from incrementing the todoListID variable.

Comment: You're right, that's the only change I made. Everything else is the same. There must be something else that is causing the issue.

Comment: Ah, I'm not sure what would be the problem in that case. Thanks for your effort though and feel free to build upon that if you'd like.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? The only other difference in my fiddle example is the version of bootstrap.

Comment: Are you using an older version? I'm using an older version of jquery so that it is compatible with the drag and drop function. Otherwise there's problems. There's an error in the jquery-migrate and bootstrap.min.

Comment: I'm using version 2.2.3 and jquery version 1.12. You'll need to resolve your errors.

Comment: One of them is wanting me to use a newer version of JQuery for Bootstrap's JS, but that would clash with my drag and drop with is a more important feature than collapsible. Give and take I guess.